# Windows Phone 7.1 - Many-To-One relation on the same table - DB

Tags: database, windows-phone-7, datatable, many-to-one

I'm trying to create a DB that has a Many-To-One relation between an object to itself.
(I have a user and the user should have a list of other users that he knows...)

*I have 2 questions:*

- I know that in order to do a Many-To-One relation between **different table** you create an entitySet on the side that should have the list and an entityRef on the other side.
  One thing I did not undertood in this process :
  In the object from the "Many" side - there are to things that are added- a id (which is the primaryKey to the "one" side, and also a object of the "one" side type. 
  Why do I need to do so-to  create an object? can't I just do the key?

code Example:

(one country-namy cities- Why there is a counrty object and alse a country Id in the city class???)

```
    [Table]
    public class Country
     {
    private EntitySet<City> citiesRef;

    public Country()
    {
        this.citiesRef = new EntitySet<City>(this.OnCityAdded, this.OnCityRemoved);
    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Association(Name = "FK_Country_Cities", Storage = "citiesRef", ThisKey = "ID", OtherKey = "CountryID")]
    public EntitySet<City> Cities
    {
        get
        {
            return this.citiesRef;
        }
    }

    private void OnCityAdded(City city)
    {
        city.Country = this;
    }

    private void OnCityRemoved(City city)
    {
        city.Country = null;
    }
}



    [Table]
    public class City
    {
    private Nullable<int> countryID;
    private EntityRef<Country> countryRef = new EntityRef<Country>();

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column(Storage = "countryID", DbType = "Int")]
    public int CountryID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.countryID;
        }
        set
        {
            this.countryID = value;
        }
    }

    [Association(Name = "FK_Country_Cities", Storage = "countryRef", ThisKey = "CountryID", OtherKey = "ID", IsForeignKey = true)]
    public Country Country
    {
        get
        {
            return this.countryRef.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            Country previousValue = this.countryRef.Entity;
            if (((previousValue != value) || (this.countryRef.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
            {
                if ((previousValue != null))
                {
                    this.countryRef.Entity = null;
                    previousValue.Cities.Remove(this);
                }
                this.countryRef.Entity = value;
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    value.Cities.Add(this);
                    this.countryID = value.ID;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.countryID = default(Nullable<int>);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- How do I create that Many-To-One relation that I want (from User to User)?
  I've tried something and it does not get me anywhere.. (Also -I don't really understand what I'm doing there- because basically the results are that each user will have a id,friendId and a friendList and I don't want the friend ID...

  ```
   [Table]
    public class User
    {
      [Column (IsPrimaryKey=true)]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      [Column]
      public string Name { get; set; }
      [Column]
      public string Gender { get; set; }

  private EntitySet<User> friends;//the list of users the user knows
  [Association(Storage = "friends", ThisKey = "Id", OtherKey = "MyFriendId")]
  public EntitySet<User> Friends
  {
      get { return friends; }
      set { friends.Assign(value); }         
  }

  public User(int _id, string _name, string _gender)
  {
      Id = _id;
      Name = _name;
      Gender = _gender;  
      Friends = new EntitySet<User>();

  }

  [Column(CanBeNull = false)]
  public int MyFriendId { get; set; }//the other user id
  EntityRef<User> myFriend;//the other user object-why??
  [Association(Storage = "myFriend", ThisKey = "MyFriendId", OtherKey = "Id", IsForeignKey = true)]
  public User MyFriend
  {
      get
      { return myFriend.Entity; }
      set
      { myFriend.Entity = value; }
  }
  ```

  }
  }

Any help? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you are trying to be to concise.  add a second table to hold the store of related users.

columns

ID,
IDOfUserWithRelations &
RelateduserID

QED.

Comment: Do you mean I sould have a table(lets call it UserRelations) that has 2 users? (meaning in the UserRelations table I will have many rows of user A with alot of other users?) wouldnt it be many to many then?

Comment: yes. it may look like this:

1 - USER1 - USER 2;  2 - USER1 - USER 3;  2 - USER1 - USER 4; 3 - USER2 - USER 5; 4 - USER2 - USER 6; etc